# Webpack hot loader will occasionally detect changes made

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've been fiddling with Webpack for the past few days. I seem to have got it to work the way i want it to. However on Windows 7 when I make a change to a file the script doesn't start another recompile. Seems to work fine on a mac OSX when I tested.

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js',
        './src/scss/main.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '/public/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'jsx', 'babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass'),
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        hot: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css', {
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()

    ]
};
```

in the browser console all I get the following

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

Any ideas how I could fix this problem? would be very helpful thanks.

Comment: or could it be related to the node modules path. When i run the webpack script it lists the following: 
`[304] ./~/react-hot-loader/isReactElementish.js 288 bytes {0} [built]
  [305] ./src/components/controls/index.js 3.93 kB {0} [built]`
would the use of ~ in the path be effecting the hot reload on windows. Would explain why it works on mac

Comment: after further investigation it would seem that it has something to do with Webstorm 2016.2.

when i use a different ide/text editor it seems to work weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Webstorm you will need to turn off: Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first)

You can do this by:
Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first)